# HTML5 Video View count

Tags: php, wordpress, video, plugins, view

Need help in counting the video view count. I am using Wordpress. Or does anyone know any plugin that will count the video views.
Also this is not embedded video. The video location is on my server.

Comment: i thing you put meta value and when page open count ++

Comment: what i did is trigger the update on button click

Comment: haven't tried any plugin so far

Comment: @bhaveshvala all the videos is in one page but they are in different page in wordpress

Comment: ok i have function please try and check

Comment: check my answer @
Richie Nepomocino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code Punt in `function.php`

```
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count;
}
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
```

Put count value use code and pass `post id` in single page

```
<?php setPostViews(1); ?>
```

Get Count value use code and pass `post id`

```
<?php getPostViews(1); ?>
```

Comment: Welcome Dear  @Richie Nepomocino